# Can I use <form:select> with List<Object> in Spring Forms?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I tried different ways to use it as `List<String>` but it didn't work.

```
<c:forEach items="${sales_contract.Positions}" var="position"
        varStatus="status">
        <select name="position[0].Position">
            <c:forEach items="${positions_list}" var="pos">
                <option value="${pos}"><c:out value="${pos.Position_Name}"></c:out></option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
</c:forEach>
```

"Positions" in forEach items is a list object under modelAttribute sales_contract.

For testing I am just trying to populate that object for 0th object in above list.

In inner forEach, positions_list is Object of type `List<Positions>`.

I also used spring form tag for that,

```
<c:forEach items="${sales_contract.Positions}" var="position"
        varStatus="status">
        <form:select path="sales_contract.Positions[${status.index}].Position"
            items="${positions_list}">
        </form:select>
</c:forEach>
```

It didn't work either. It is not generating any error, but nothing is showing up on the form.

Model structure is below,

SalesContract

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
private long external_id;

private long ID;

private String Sales_Rep;

private long Sales_Contract_Number;

private Date Order_Date;
private String Status;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="account_id")
private Account Account;

private String Contact;

private String shipping_add_identifier;
private String shipping_address_name;
private String shipping_c_o;
private String Shipping_Street;
private String Shipping_City;
private String Shipping_State;
private String Shipping_Zip_Code;
private String Shipping_Country;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String Carrier_Instructions;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String Warehouse_Instructions;

private String Terms;
private BigDecimal Hold_for_Funds;
private String Credit_Card_Fee;
private String Carrier;
private String Shipping_Cost_Payment;
private boolean Expedite;
private BigDecimal Total_Amount_usd;
private BigDecimal Total_Amount_RMB;
private BigDecimal Pre_Payments_Requested;
private BigDecimal Payments_Made;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String Customer_Comment;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
private List<SalesOrderPosition> Positions;

public long getSales_contract_id() {
    return external_id;
}

public long getExternal_id() {
    return external_id;
}

public void setExternal_id(long external_id) {
    this.external_id = external_id;
}

public long getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(long iD) {
    ID = iD;
}

public String getShipping_add_identifier() {
    return shipping_add_identifier;
}

public void setShipping_add_identifier(String shipping_add_identifier) {
    this.shipping_add_identifier = shipping_add_identifier;
}

public String getShipping_address_name() {
    return shipping_address_name;
}

public void setShipping_address_name(String shipping_address_name) {
    this.shipping_address_name = shipping_address_name;
}

public String getShipping_c_o() {
    return shipping_c_o;
}

public void setShipping_c_o(String shipping_c_o) {
    this.shipping_c_o = shipping_c_o;
}

public void setSales_contract_id(long sales_contract_id) {
    this.external_id = sales_contract_id;
}

public String getSales_Rep() {
    return Sales_Rep;
}

public void setSales_Rep(String sales_Rep) {
    Sales_Rep = sales_Rep;
}

public long getSales_Contract_Number() {
    return Sales_Contract_Number;
}

public void setSales_Contract_Number(long sales_Contract_Number) {
    Sales_Contract_Number = sales_Contract_Number;
}

public Date getOrder_Date() {
    return Order_Date;
}

public void setOrder_Date(Date order_Date) {
    Order_Date = order_Date;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return Status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    Status = status;
}

public Account getAccount() {
    return Account;
}

public void setAccount(Account account) {
    Account = account;
}

public String getContact() {
    return Contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    Contact = contact;
}

public String getShipping_Street() {
    return Shipping_Street;
}

public void setShipping_Street(String shipping_Street) {
    Shipping_Street = shipping_Street;
}

public String getShipping_City() {
    return Shipping_City;
}

public void setShipping_City(String shipping_City) {
    Shipping_City = shipping_City;
}

public String getShipping_State() {
    return Shipping_State;
}

public void setShipping_State(String shipping_State) {
    Shipping_State = shipping_State;
}

public String getShipping_Zip_Code() {
    return Shipping_Zip_Code;
}

public void setShipping_Zip_Code(String shipping_Zip_Code) {
    Shipping_Zip_Code = shipping_Zip_Code;
}

public String getShipping_Country() {
    return Shipping_Country;
}

public void setShipping_Country(String shipping_Country) {
    Shipping_Country = shipping_Country;
}

public String getCarrier_Instructions() {
    return Carrier_Instructions;
}

public void setCarrier_Instructions(String carrier_Instructions) {
    Carrier_Instructions = carrier_Instructions;
}

public String getWarehouse_Instructions() {
    return Warehouse_Instructions;
}

public void setWarehouse_Instructions(String warehouse_Instructions) {
    Warehouse_Instructions = warehouse_Instructions;
}

public String getTerms() {
    return Terms;
}

public void setTerms(String terms) {
    Terms = terms;
}

public BigDecimal getHold_for_Funds() {
    return Hold_for_Funds;
}

public void setHold_for_Funds(BigDecimal hold_for_Funds) {
    Hold_for_Funds = hold_for_Funds;
}

public String getCredit_Card_Fee() {
    return Credit_Card_Fee;
}

public void setCredit_Card_Fee(String credit_Card_Fee) {
    Credit_Card_Fee = credit_Card_Fee;
}

public String getCarrier() {
    return Carrier;
}

public void setCarrier(String carrier) {
    Carrier = carrier;
}

public String getShipping_Cost_Payment() {
    return Shipping_Cost_Payment;
}

public void setShipping_Cost_Payment(String shipping_Cost_Payment) {
    Shipping_Cost_Payment = shipping_Cost_Payment;
}

public boolean isExpedite() {
    return Expedite;
}

public void setExpedite(boolean expedite) {
    Expedite = expedite;
}

public BigDecimal getTotal_Amount_usd() {
    return Total_Amount_usd;
}

public void setTotal_Amount_usd(BigDecimal total_Amount_usd) {
    Total_Amount_usd = total_Amount_usd;
}

public BigDecimal getTotal_Amount_RMB() {
    return Total_Amount_RMB;
}

public void setTotal_Amount_RMB(BigDecimal total_Amount_RMB) {
    Total_Amount_RMB = total_Amount_RMB;
}

public BigDecimal getPre_Payments_Requested() {
    return Pre_Payments_Requested;
}

public void setPre_Payments_Requested(BigDecimal pre_Payments_Requested) {
    Pre_Payments_Requested = pre_Payments_Requested;
}

public BigDecimal getPayments_Made() {
    return Payments_Made;
}

public void setPayments_Made(BigDecimal payments_Made) {
    Payments_Made = payments_Made;
}

public String getCustomer_Comment() {
    return Customer_Comment;
}

public void setCustomer_Comment(String customer_Comment) {
    Customer_Comment = customer_Comment;
}

public List<SalesOrderPosition> getPositions() {
    return Positions;
}

public void setPositions(List<SalesOrderPosition> positions) {
    Positions = positions;
}
```

Positions:

```
    @Id
private long ID;

private String Product;
private String Lot;
private String Position_Name;
private String Location;
private String Final_Warehouse;
private boolean Warehouse_Open;
private String ETA_final_Warehouse;
private String Spot_String_current_Warehouse;
private boolean Contract_Price_Fixed;
private String Landed_Price_per_lb;
private String Landed_Differential;
private String Price_Adjustment_ct_lb;
private String Work_Order_Costs;
private String Price_Per_lb;
private String Differential;
private boolean Do_Not_Sell;
private boolean Do_Not_Ship;
private String UoM_Type;
private String Weight_per_Unit_in_kgs;
private String Weight_per_Unit_in_lbs;
private Integer Original_Quantity;
private Integer Quantity_Available_For_Sale;
private Integer Quantity_Sold;
private Integer Quantity_Processed;
private Integer Quantity_on_Work_Orders;
private Integer Quantity_Physically_Available;
private String Landed_Score;

public long getID() {
    return ID;
}
public void setID(long iD) {
    ID = iD;
}
public String getProduct() {
    return Product;
}
public void setProduct(String product) {
    Product = product;
}
public String getLot() {
    return Lot;
}
public void setLot(String lot) {
    Lot = lot;
}
public String getPosition_Name() {
    return Position_Name;
}
public void setPosition_Name(String position_Name) {
    Position_Name = position_Name;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return Location;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
    Location = location;
}
public String getFinal_Warehouse() {
    return Final_Warehouse;
}
public void setFinal_Warehouse(String final_Warehouse) {
    Final_Warehouse = final_Warehouse;
}
public boolean isWarehouse_Open() {
    return Warehouse_Open;
}
public void setWarehouse_Open(boolean warehouse_Open) {
    Warehouse_Open = warehouse_Open;
}
public String getETA_final_Warehouse() {
    return ETA_final_Warehouse;
}
public void setETA_final_Warehouse(String eTA_final_Warehouse) {
    ETA_final_Warehouse = eTA_final_Warehouse;
}
public String getSpot_String_current_Warehouse() {
    return Spot_String_current_Warehouse;
}
public void setSpot_String_current_Warehouse(String spot_String_current_Warehouse) {
    Spot_String_current_Warehouse = spot_String_current_Warehouse;
}
public boolean isContract_Price_Fixed() {
    return Contract_Price_Fixed;
}
public void setContract_Price_Fixed(boolean contract_Price_Fixed) {
    Contract_Price_Fixed = contract_Price_Fixed;
}
public String getLanded_Price_per_lb() {
    return Landed_Price_per_lb;
}
public void setLanded_Price_per_lb(String landed_Price_per_lb) {
    Landed_Price_per_lb = landed_Price_per_lb;
}
public String getLanded_Differential() {
    return Landed_Differential;
}
public void setLanded_Differential(String landed_Differential) {
    Landed_Differential = landed_Differential;
}
public String getPrice_Adjustment_ct_lb() {
    return Price_Adjustment_ct_lb;
}
public void setPrice_Adjustment_ct_lb(String price_Adjustment_ct_lb) {
    Price_Adjustment_ct_lb = price_Adjustment_ct_lb;
}
public String getWork_Order_Costs() {
    return Work_Order_Costs;
}
public void setWork_Order_Costs(String work_Order_Costs) {
    Work_Order_Costs = work_Order_Costs;
}
public String getPrice_Per_lb() {
    return Price_Per_lb;
}
public void setPrice_Per_lb(String price_Per_lb) {
    Price_Per_lb = price_Per_lb;
}
public String getDifferential() {
    return Differential;
}
public void setDifferential(String differential) {
    Differential = differential;
}
public boolean isDo_Not_Sell() {
    return Do_Not_Sell;
}
public void setDo_Not_Sell(boolean do_Not_Sell) {
    Do_Not_Sell = do_Not_Sell;
}
public boolean isDo_Not_Ship() {
    return Do_Not_Ship;
}
public void setDo_Not_Ship(boolean do_Not_Ship) {
    Do_Not_Ship = do_Not_Ship;
}
public String getUoM_Type() {
    return UoM_Type;
}
public void setUoM_Type(String uoM_Type) {
    UoM_Type = uoM_Type;
}
public String getWeight_per_Unit_in_kgs() {
    return Weight_per_Unit_in_kgs;
}
public void setWeight_per_Unit_in_kgs(String weight_per_Unit_in_kgs) {
    Weight_per_Unit_in_kgs = weight_per_Unit_in_kgs;
}
public String getWeight_per_Unit_in_lbs() {
    return Weight_per_Unit_in_lbs;
}
public void setWeight_per_Unit_in_lbs(String weight_per_Unit_in_lbs) {
    Weight_per_Unit_in_lbs = weight_per_Unit_in_lbs;
}
public Integer getOriginal_Quantity() {
    return Original_Quantity;
}
public void setOriginal_Quantity(Integer original_Quantity) {
    Original_Quantity = original_Quantity;
}
public Integer getQuantity_Available_For_Sale() {
    return Quantity_Available_For_Sale;
}
public void setQuantity_Available_For_Sale(Integer quantity_Available_For_Sale) {
    Quantity_Available_For_Sale = quantity_Available_For_Sale;
}
public Integer getQuantity_Sold() {
    return Quantity_Sold;
}
public void setQuantity_Sold(Integer quantity_Sold) {
    Quantity_Sold = quantity_Sold;
}
public Integer getQuantity_Processed() {
    return Quantity_Processed;
}
public void setQuantity_Processed(Integer quantity_Processed) {
    Quantity_Processed = quantity_Processed;
}
public Integer getQuantity_on_Work_Orders() {
    return Quantity_on_Work_Orders;
}
public void setQuantity_on_Work_Orders(Integer quantity_on_Work_Orders) {
    Quantity_on_Work_Orders = quantity_on_Work_Orders;
}
public Integer getQuantity_Physically_Available() {
    return Quantity_Physically_Available;
}
public void setQuantity_Physically_Available(Integer quantity_Physically_Available) {
    Quantity_Physically_Available = quantity_Physically_Available;
}
public String getLanded_Score() {
    return Landed_Score;
}
public void setLanded_Score(String landed_Score) {
    Landed_Score = landed_Score;
}
```

SalesOrderPosition:

```
@Id
private long ID;

private String Position;
private String Service;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String Add_Description;

private Integer Qty_Ordered;

private BigDecimal Weight_per_Unit_kgs;
private BigDecimal Weight_per_Unit_lbs;

private String Price_Fixed;
private BigDecimal Price_kg;
private BigDecimal Price_lb;
private BigDecimal Market_Price_kg;
private BigDecimal Market_Price_lb;
private BigDecimal Differential_ct_lb;
private BigDecimal Margin_ct_lb;
private String CC_Fee_Rate;
private BigDecimal CC_Fee;
private BigDecimal Carry_Rate_per_Month;
private BigDecimal Carry_Cost;
private BigDecimal Final_Price_kg;
private BigDecimal Final_Price_RMB_kg;
private BigDecimal Amount_usd;
private BigDecimal Amount_RMB;
private String Terms;
private Date Custom_Due_Date;
private String Incoterms;
private String Weight_Terms;
private String Shipping_Address;
private boolean Ship_to_Customer;
private Date Shipping_Date;
private String Ship_ASAP;
private String Ship_Month;
private Integer Qty_on_Ship_Order;
private Integer Qty_Shipped;
private String SAS_Code;
private String Customer_PO;
private String Comment;
private String Status;

public long getId() {
    return ID;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.ID = id;
}
public String getPosition() {
    return Position;
}
public void setPosition(String position) {
    Position = position;
}
public String getService() {
    return Service;
}
public void setService(String service) {
    Service = service;
}
public String getAdd_Description() {
    return Add_Description;
}
public void setAdd_Description(String add_Description) {
    Add_Description = add_Description;
}
public Integer getQty_Ordered() {
    return Qty_Ordered;
}
public void setQty_Ordered(Integer qty_Ordered) {
    Qty_Ordered = qty_Ordered;
}
public BigDecimal getWeight_per_Unit_kgs() {
    return Weight_per_Unit_kgs;
}
public void setWeight_per_Unit_kgs(BigDecimal weight_per_Unit_kgs) {
    Weight_per_Unit_kgs = weight_per_Unit_kgs;
}
public BigDecimal getWeight_per_Unit_lbs() {
    return Weight_per_Unit_lbs;
}
public void setWeight_per_Unit_lbs(BigDecimal weight_per_Unit_lbs) {
    Weight_per_Unit_lbs = weight_per_Unit_lbs;
}
public String getPrice_Fixed() {
    return Price_Fixed;
}
public void setPrice_Fixed(String price_Fixed) {
    Price_Fixed = price_Fixed;
}
public BigDecimal getPrice_kg() {
    return Price_kg;
}
public void setPrice_kg(BigDecimal price_kg) {
    Price_kg = price_kg;
}
public BigDecimal getPrice_lb() {
    return Price_lb;
}
public void setPrice_lb(BigDecimal price_lb) {
    Price_lb = price_lb;
}
public BigDecimal getMarket_Price_kg() {
    return Market_Price_kg;
}
public void setMarket_Price_kg(BigDecimal market_Price_kg) {
    Market_Price_kg = market_Price_kg;
}
public BigDecimal getMarket_Price_lb() {
    return Market_Price_lb;
}
public void setMarket_Price_lb(BigDecimal market_Price_lb) {
    Market_Price_lb = market_Price_lb;
}
public BigDecimal getDifferential_ct_lb() {
    return Differential_ct_lb;
}
public void setDifferential_ct_lb(BigDecimal differential_ct_lb) {
    Differential_ct_lb = differential_ct_lb;
}
public BigDecimal getMargin_ct_lb() {
    return Margin_ct_lb;
}
public void setMargin_ct_lb(BigDecimal margin_ct_lb) {
    Margin_ct_lb = margin_ct_lb;
}
public String getCC_Fee_Rate() {
    return CC_Fee_Rate;
}
public void setCC_Fee_Rate(String cC_Fee_Rate) {
    CC_Fee_Rate = cC_Fee_Rate;
}
public BigDecimal getCC_Fee() {
    return CC_Fee;
}
public void setCC_Fee(BigDecimal cC_Fee) {
    CC_Fee = cC_Fee;
}
public BigDecimal getCarry_Rate_per_Month() {
    return Carry_Rate_per_Month;
}
public void setCarry_Rate_per_Month(BigDecimal carry_Rate_per_Month) {
    Carry_Rate_per_Month = carry_Rate_per_Month;
}
public BigDecimal getCarry_Cost() {
    return Carry_Cost;
}
public void setCarry_Cost(BigDecimal carry_Cost) {
    Carry_Cost = carry_Cost;
}
public BigDecimal getFinal_Price_kg() {
    return Final_Price_kg;
}
public void setFinal_Price_kg(BigDecimal final_Price_kg) {
    Final_Price_kg = final_Price_kg;
}
public BigDecimal getFinal_Price_RMB_kg() {
    return Final_Price_RMB_kg;
}
public void setFinal_Price_RMB_kg(BigDecimal final_Price_RMB_kg) {
    Final_Price_RMB_kg = final_Price_RMB_kg;
}
public BigDecimal getAmount_usd() {
    return Amount_usd;
}
public void setAmount_usd(BigDecimal amount_usd) {
    Amount_usd = amount_usd;
}
public BigDecimal getAmount_RMB() {
    return Amount_RMB;
}
public void setAmount_RMB(BigDecimal amount_RMB) {
    Amount_RMB = amount_RMB;
}
public String getTerms() {
    return Terms;
}
public void setTerms(String terms) {
    Terms = terms;
}
public Date getCustom_Due_Date() {
    return Custom_Due_Date;
}
public void setCustom_Due_Date(Date custom_Due_Date) {
    Custom_Due_Date = custom_Due_Date;
}
public String getIncoterms() {
    return Incoterms;
}
public void setIncoterms(String incoterms) {
    Incoterms = incoterms;
}
public String getWeight_Terms() {
    return Weight_Terms;
}
public void setWeight_Terms(String weight_Terms) {
    Weight_Terms = weight_Terms;
}
public String getShipping_Address() {
    return Shipping_Address;
}
public void setShipping_Address(String shipping_Address) {
    Shipping_Address = shipping_Address;
}
public boolean isShip_to_Customer() {
    return Ship_to_Customer;
}
public void setShip_to_Customer(boolean ship_to_Customer) {
    Ship_to_Customer = ship_to_Customer;
}
public Date getShipping_Date() {
    return Shipping_Date;
}
public void setShipping_Date(Date shipping_Date) {
    Shipping_Date = shipping_Date;
}
public String getShip_ASAP() {
    return Ship_ASAP;
}
public void setShip_ASAP(String ship_ASAP) {
    Ship_ASAP = ship_ASAP;
}
public String getShip_Month() {
    return Ship_Month;
}
public void setShip_Month(String ship_Month) {
    Ship_Month = ship_Month;
}
public Integer getQty_on_Ship_Order() {
    return Qty_on_Ship_Order;
}
public void setQty_on_Ship_Order(Integer qty_on_Ship_Order) {
    Qty_on_Ship_Order = qty_on_Ship_Order;
}
public Integer getQty_Shipped() {
    return Qty_Shipped;
}
public void setQty_Shipped(Integer qty_Shipped) {
    Qty_Shipped = qty_Shipped;
}
public String getSAS_Code() {
    return SAS_Code;
}
public void setSAS_Code(String sAS_Code) {
    SAS_Code = sAS_Code;
}
public String getCustomer_PO() {
    return Customer_PO;
}
public void setCustomer_PO(String customer_PO) {
    Customer_PO = customer_PO;
}
public String getComment() {
    return Comment;
}
public void setComment(String comment) {
    Comment = comment;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return Status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    Status = status;
}
```

Finally, mapping is like this, SalesContract has a list object of type SalesOrderPosition, which has a property called position of String type. Which must be written from Position class that is used as dropdown list in jsp with the name positions_list. I just want to use Position_Name field from Position class to fill out Position in SalesOrderPosition for multiple rows, so I am trying to use `<c:forEach>` tag.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some code of your tries?

Comment: Just added. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your model structure of Position and sales_contract

Comment: Added model structures to it.